# Cannot 'convert' from Vector{struct} to UnionAll

Tags: julia

In my Julia code, I have created a mutable struct that I am going to call X. Then, I create a matrix as follows:

```
result = fill(X, (J, N))
```

with J and N being integers. Then, I call a function J times; each call creates an array of N objects of type X, and I have a simple assignment as follows:

```
for n = 1:N     result[j, n] = X[n]     end
```

However, Julia complains with the following error: "Load Error: MethodError: Cannot 'convert' an object of type X to an object of type UnionAll.

I am a newbie to Julia; thanks for your (detailed) help!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code? Preferably a _minimal_ example that reproduces the issue. What is `X`? Is it the name of a type, is it a variable containing an instance of your type, or is it a variable containing an array of instances? Your example code is unfortunately ambiguous and incomplete.

Comment: I have a hunch the error is occurring in the function called J times, not the bits of code that were pasted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there may be a very simple issue here that is misdirecting you toward the wrong presumed cause.

For instance, I built up an example based on what you said:

```
julia> struct Foo 
         a::Int32
         b::Float64
       end

julia> fill(Foo(3,1.2), (3,4))
3×4 Matrix{Foo}:
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)

julia> x = fill(Foo(3,1.2), (3,4))
3×4 Matrix{Foo}:
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)

julia> x[2,3] = Foo(1,π)
Foo(1, 3.141592653589793)
julia> x
3×4 Matrix{Foo}:
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)      Foo(3, 1.2)
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(1, 3.14159)  Foo(3, 1.2)
 Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)  Foo(3, 1.2)      Foo(3, 1.2)

julia>
```

This seems to work fine. The difference from your code is that I am calling the constructor for `Foo` which means that I used round brackets (parentheses). You used square brackets which indicates indexing, not object creation. Types (like X) are not normally indexed.